# Нужна ли запятая после местоимения «это»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

> Заметив это(,) девушка только сильнее засмущалась.

Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая после указательного местоимения "это"?

Answer (score 1):

После местоимения [**это**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE) (оно заменяет то, о чём говорится в предшествующем или последующем предложении) обязательно нужна запятая, так как конструкция "заметив это" является деепричастным оборотом. А деепричастные обороты, как всем известно, выделяются запятыми.
[*Заметив* — деепричастие прошедшего времени от *заметить*.]

*Клементьев откровенно зевнул, прикрывая рот ладонью. **Заметив это,** старлей предложил:

― Товарищ майор, устроить вас с товарищем капитаном на ночлег?*
А. А. Бушков. Дверь в чужую осень (сборник)

*— Спасибо, — ей так хотелось лечь, что все силы уходили на то, чтобы держать спину.

**Заметив это,** Бемби отчаянным голосом спросила:

— Уже пора?*
Юлия Лавряшина. Улитка в тарелке

*Стража тут же начала спешиваться. **Заметив это,** он строго сказал:

— Ждать здесь.*
Борис Васильев. Ольга, королева русов

[Обособленные обстоятельства. Деепричастные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113)

Answer (score 0):

Деепричастный оборот – это деепричастие с зависимыми словами. Как и одиночное деепричастие, обозначает добавочное действие и совершается тем же лицом, предметом или явлением, которое совершает основное действие. **Всегда обособляется.** Отвечает на вопрос «что делая?» или «что сделав?». Действие обычно относится к подлежащему, например: подводя итоги встречи, министр поздравил всех учителей с началом учебного года.

Деепричастие — это самостоятельная часть речи в русском языке, которая обозначает добавочное действие при основном. В этой части речи сочетаются признаки глагола (вид, залог и возвратность) и наречия (неизменяемость, синтаксическая роль обстоятельства). Отвечает на вопросы что делая? что сделав?

Так как оборот **всегда обособляется**, то в вашем случае запятую необходимо поставить

Comment: Приветствую Вас на сайте, Александр! Скажите, а что смотреть по указанной ссылке — ударения?